# PowerShell Reverse CSV-data

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

On the web I found this function to import data from an Excel sheet in PowerShell. I've tried to enhance it a bit which worked out quite well. However, the last hurdle I need to take is to reverse the data. As not all the data in the Excel sheet is aligned vertically, but sometimes also horizontally. I think it might become more clear with an example.

**Example of 'Test.xlsx':**

```
Below you will find all the parameters:
Header 1 | Text 1 | Text 11
Header 2 | Text 2 | Text 22
Header 3 | Text 3 | Text 33
```

**Current wrong result:**

```
Header 1  Text 1  Text 11
--------  ------  -------
Header 2  Text 2  Text 22
Header 3  Text 3  Text 33
```

**Desired result:**

```
Header 1  Header 2  Header 3
--------  --------  --------
Text 1    Text 2    Text 3
Text 11   Text 22   Text 33
```

So as you can see, in some way or another I need to be able to reverse the data columns and headers to get it all correct. It would be nice if this could be added to the function in the way of a `Switch`. So that when it's not needed, it's still able to import rows and columns in the old way.

**Function:**

```
Function Import-Excel {

    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [String]$FileName, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String]$WorksheetName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
        [Int]$SkipLines
    )

    $csvFile = Join-Path $env:temp ("{0}.csv" -f (Get-Item -path $FileName).BaseName)
    if (Test-Path -path $csvFile) { Remove-Item -path $csvFile }

        Function FindSheet([Object]$workbook, [string]$name)
        {
            $sheetNumber = 0
            for ($i=1; $i -le $workbook.Sheets.Count; $i++) {
                if ($name -eq $workbook.Sheets.Item($i).Name) { $sheetNumber = $i; break }
            }
            return $sheetNumber
        }

        Function SetActiveSheet([Object]$workbook, [string]$name)
        {
            if (!$name) { return }
            $sheetNumber = FindSheet $workbook $name
            if ($sheetNumber -gt 0) { $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetNumber).Activate() }
            return ($sheetNumber -gt 0)
        }

        # convert Excel file to CSV file
        $xlCSVType = 6 # SEE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx
        $excelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  
        $excelObject.Visible = $false 
        $workbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Open($FileName)

        # check if worksheet exists
        foreach ($sheet in $workbookObject.Worksheets) {
            if ($Sheet.Name -eq $WorksheetName) {
                $SheetAvailable = $true
            }
        }
        if (-not $SheetAvailable) {
            $workbookObject.Close()
            $excelObject.Quit()
            throw "Import-Excel: Worksheet '$WorksheetName' not found in workbook '$FileName'"
        }

        SetActiveSheet $workbookObject $WorksheetName | Out-Null
        $workbookObject.SaveAs($csvFile,$xlCSVType) 
        $workbookObject.Saved = $true
        $workbookObject.Close()

         # cleanup 
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbookObject) | Out-Null
        $excelObject.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelObject) | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

        # import and return the data 
        $Result = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | Select-Object -Skip $SkipLines | Where {$_ -notmatch "^[,]+$"} | ConvertFrom-Csv
        Write-Output $Result
}

Import-Excel C:\Test.xlsx -WorksheetName 'Parameters' -SkipLines 1
```

As always guys, thank you for your help.

**Solution thanks to TheMadTechnician:**

```
Function Import-Excel {

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [String]$FileName, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String]$WorksheetName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
        [Int]$SkipLines=0,
        [Switch]$Reverse
    )
    BEGIN {
        $csvFile = Join-Path $env:temp ("{0}.csv" -f (Get-Item -path $FileName).BaseName)
        if (Test-Path -path $csvFile) { Remove-Item -path $csvFile }
    }
    PROCESS {
        # Convert Excel file to CSV file
        $xlCSVType = 6 # SEE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx
        $excelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  
        $excelObject.Visible = $false 
        $workbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Open($FileName)

        # Check if worksheet exists
        $ws1 = $workbookObject.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq $WorksheetName}
        if ($ws1 -ne $Null) {
            $ws1.Activate()
        }
        else {
            $workbookObject.Close($false)
            $excelObject.Quit()
            throw "Import-Excel: Worksheet '$WorksheetName' not found in workbook '$FileName'"
        }

        If($Reverse){
            $usedRange = $workbookObject.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            $ws = $workbookObject.ActiveSheet

            # Remove first lines
            for ($i = 1; $i -le $SkipLines; $i++) {
                [void]$ws.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete()
            }

            # Remove empty lines
            $lastCell = $usedRange.SpecialCells(11) 
            $row = $lastCell.row 

            for ($i = 1; $i -le $row; $i++) {
                If ($ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value() -eq $Null) {
                    $Range = $ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).EntireRow
                    $Range.Delete() | Out-Null
                }
            }

            $usedRange.Copy() | Out-Null
            $newWorkbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Add()
            $newWorkbookObject.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(12,-4142,$false,$true)| Out-Null

            $newWorkbookObject.SaveAs($csvFile,$xlCSVType) 
            $newWorkbookObject.Saved = $true
            $newWorkbookObject.Close()
            $workbookObject.Close($false)

            # Pause to let the CSV be written
            While(!(Test-Path $csvFile)){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50}

            # Import and return the data 
            $Result = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | ConvertFrom-Csv
            Write-Output $Result
        }
        Else{
            $WorkbookObject.SaveAs($csvFile,$xlCSVType) 
            $WorkbookObject.Saved = $true
            $workbookObject.Close()

            # Pause to let the CSV be written
            While(!(Test-Path $csvFile)){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50}

            # Import and return the data 
            $Result = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | Select-Object -Skip $SkipLines | Where {$_ -notmatch "^[,]+$"} | ConvertFrom-Csv
            Write-Output $Result
        }
        # Cleanup 
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbookObject) | Out-Null
        If($Reverse){[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($newWorkbookObject) | Out-Null}
        $excelObject.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelObject) | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }
}

Import-Excel C:\Test.xlsx -WorksheetName 'Parameters' -Reverse -SkipLines 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. Add this to the parameter section `[Switch]$Reverse` and replace the end of the code with this:

```
# import and return the data 
$Result = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | Select-Object -Skip $SkipLines | Where {$_ -notmatch "^[,]+$"} 

if ($Reverse) {
    $Result | ForEach-Object {$Header += "$($_.Split(',')[0]),"; $Content += "$($_.Split(',')[1]),"}
    $Result = "$Header`n$Content"
}

$Obj = $Result | ConvertFrom-Csv
Write-Output $Obj
```

Comment: You should mark your answer as done (there should be a tick to the right of it).

Comment: I can only mark my own question as solved after 2 days according to the site.

Comment: This will fail with data where fields are quoted and contain delimiters as well.

Comment: That's true, I noticed it recently.. There's also a problem when you want to import multiple cells under one header. Looking for a better way..

Answer (score 1):

What I think would have been a cleaner solution would be to take the UsedRange, copy it, paste special with Transpose, and then process it as usual. Here is your entire function modified to do that:

```
Function Import-Excel {

    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf })]
        [String]$FileName, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String]$WorksheetName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
        [Int]$SkipLines=0,
        [Switch]$Reverse
    )

    $csvFile = Join-Path $env:temp ("{0}.csv" -f (Get-Item -path $FileName).BaseName)
    if (Test-Path -path $csvFile) { Remove-Item -path $csvFile }

        Function FindSheet([Object]$workbook, [string]$name)
        {
            $sheetNumber = 0
            for ($i=1; $i -le $workbook.Sheets.Count; $i++) {
                if ($name -eq $workbook.Sheets.Item($i).Name) { $sheetNumber = $i; break }
            }
            return $sheetNumber
        }

        Function SetActiveSheet([Object]$workbook, [string]$name)
        {
            if (!$name) { return }
            $sheetNumber = FindSheet $workbook $name
            if ($sheetNumber -gt 0) { $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetNumber).Activate() }
            return ($sheetNumber -gt 0)
        }

        # convert Excel file to CSV file
        $xlCSVType = 6 # SEE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx
        $excelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  
        $excelObject.Visible = $false 
        $workbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Open($FileName)

        # check if worksheet exists
        foreach ($sheet in $workbookObject.Worksheets) {
            if ($Sheet.Name -eq $WorksheetName) {
                $SheetAvailable = $true
            }
        }
        if (-not $SheetAvailable) {
            $workbookObject.Close()
            $excelObject.Quit()
            throw "Import-Excel: Worksheet '$WorksheetName' not found in workbook '$FileName'"
        }

        SetActiveSheet $workbookObject $WorksheetName | Out-Null
        If($Reverse){
            $usedRange = $workbookObject.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            $usedRange.Copy() | Out-Null
            $newWorkbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Add()
            $newWorkbookObject.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(12,-4142,$false,$true)|out-null
            $newWorkbookObject.SaveAs($csvFile,$xlCSVType) 
            $newWorkbookObject.Saved = $true
            $newWorkbookObject.Close()
        }Else{
            $WorkbookObject.SaveAs($csvFile,$xlCSVType) 
            $WorkbookObject.Saved = $true
            $workbookObject.Close()
        }

         # cleanup 
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbookObject) | Out-Null
        If($Reverse){[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($newWorkbookObject) | Out-Null}
        $excelObject.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelObject) | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

        # Pause to let the CSV be written...
        While(!Test-Path $csvFile){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50}

        # import and return the data 
        $Result = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | Select-Object -Skip $SkipLines | Where {$_ -notmatch "^[,]+$"} | ConvertFrom-Csv
        Write-Output $Result
}

Import-Excel C:\Test.xlsx -WorksheetName 'Parameters' -SkipLines 1
```

Ok, so originally I missed the `.ActiveSheet` in `$UsedRange = $workbookObject.ActiveSheet.UsedRange`, but that's fixed now. I also put in a While loop to make sure the CSV is written before we try to parse it for the `$Result =` line. I also added a out-null after the `PasteSpecial` line, to suppress the True response on screen. This works, I just had initial issues because my XLSX I was testing on had blank lines that, when transposed, caused empty headers, and that's not cool. Plus I had the same value in G1, H1, and I1, so it was trying to use the same header for three columns, and that silently fails so it would just respond with nothing. No error, nothing. Frustrating to troubleshoot. Anyway, I tested this, and it worked for me.

Comment: It's probably me, but if I try it out with your suggestion it errors out. Could you possible copy the whole function? I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Wasn't you. If nothing else I was missing .ActiveSheet in my $UsedRange= line. Updated, tested, and should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you :) I fixed some other issues to in the meantime :) The OP has been updated with the solution. If you see points for improvement, please let me know.